# Confluent Rest Proxy Schem registry does not throw an error when sending missing property key

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, kafka-rest

I register a Schema with the Schema registry as follows:

```
{ Prop1:val1,
prop2:val2,
prop3:val3}
```

all fields above are optional

When I send data payload via Rest Proxy that looks like the following:

`{ "":val1, Prop2:val2, Prop3:val3 }`

I expect the schema registry to throw an error. but that is not happening. the data goes through to the sink connector and the first key/value pair is ignored.

Is this expected behavior? How do I force an error if the properties are not present (the property is optional, but when we send a blank property, it should throw an error).

Comment: That isn't a valid Avro schema... Please be more clear on the data you have and which connector you are using

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the schema resolution in Avro.

> if the writer's record contains a field with a name not present in the
>   reader's record, the writer's value for that field is ignored.

from:
https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#Schema+Resolution

bascially in my schema repo in confluent - I reqistered a schema to take 3 properties - all optional.

```
{
propA:val1,
propB:val2,
propC:val3
}
```

if I send a data packet with additional properties or properties that do not exost in the registered schema, they are just ignored.

```
{
"":val1, //<- considered as new property and ignored
propB:val2,
propC:val3
}
```